# How can I add a "aar" library to the AOSP?

Tags: java, android-source, aar

I am building my own ROM and want to use a aar file Library in one system service.

Is there any way this could be achieved?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Android.bp` this can be done via `android_library_import` module type ([link to soong spec](https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/7967930/linux/latest/raw/java.html#android_library_import)).

Also, if you try to grep the AOSP source tree, you will easily find many examples of its use, for example: [packages/apps/Settings/Android.bp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/refs/heads/master/Android.bp#112):

```
android_library_import {
name: "contextualcards",
aars: ["libs/contextualcards.aar"],
}

android_library {
name: "Settings-core",
....   
srcs: ["src/**/*.java"],
static_libs: [
    ...
    "contextualcards",
    ...
}
```

Comment: In your `android_library_import` also add `sdk_version: "current",`